# What happens when you set a Month Timer Trigger to fire on the 31st for a month that doesn't have 31 days?

Tags: google-apps-script

In a Google Apps Script project, you can set a Time-driven trigger to fire on a monthly basis.
For example, on the 31st of every month.

What is the behavior if it is set to a day that does not exist in the current month?
For example, will a monthly trigger fire in February if it is set to fire on the 31st?
Will it end up firing on the last day of that month?

Comment: Try it in 15 days and see :)  probably will happen on the 1st

Comment: Yes, I've set one up for this month, but was hoping someone would be able to answer it for me sooner.

Comment: post back your experiment. But to be safe I wouldnt count on such undefined behaviour to continue behaving like you will find. If you want to process things at the end of the month better set a daily trigger and first thing in the code check if its the last day of the month. Will consume very little quota to just check once a day.

Comment: Ive made that suggestion an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to be safe I wouldnt count on such undefined behaviour to continue behaving like it happens to behave today.

If you want to process things at the end of the month better set a daily trigger and first thing in the code check if its the last day of the month. Will consume very little quota to just check once a day.

Store in script properties the date you last processed to know if you need to run it or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
That's probably what I'll end up doing.

Answer (score 6):

I set a trigger to fire on the 31st, but there being no 31st day in November, the trigger did not fire at all.
Also, there was no execution failure notification sent.

So, Zig Mandel's suggestion would be the best way to setup a trigger for the last day of the month.

[image: Trigger Setting]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your result, this is helpful for me personally, because I have several triggers that should be running on the last day of the month to do regular reporting functions. Good to know that I have to code around this edge case - not too big of a deal, but good to know this particular behavior of Triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I set my trigger to fire Midnight-1am on the 1st of each month.

Since the Javascript Date.getMonth() function returns 0-11, this works great, except for January (0), has to be changed to 12...

Unless this is a REALLY time sensitive issue, it should fit your needs...