# Sending email reminders for Google Sheet tasks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Updated the code based on suggestions below, The email does not contain the summary, any help fix this would be appreciated! The test file is attached below,

```
function sendEmail(){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2021-12 {3600950}").activate();
    var ss = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
    //data on sheet, filter for any row where the status is still "assigned"
     var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
        var assigned = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
     if(curr[5] === "assigned") {
         acc.push(curr)
       }
      return acc
      },[])

   // unique list of emails
    var Assignee = [0]
    var Summary = [2]

     var compareAssignee = []
     for (i=0; i<assigned.length; i++){
     compareAssignee.push(assigned[i][0])
     }
    //loop unique emails, all the tasks for each of those users, and send a simple email with the tasks

      for (var i=0; i<Assignee.length; i++){
      var Summary = assigned.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
       if(curr[0] === Assignee[i])
       {
    acc.push(String.fromCharCode() + "pending task: " + curr[2] + 
  Summary[2]) 

    //this puts a line break before each task, so when the email is 
 sent each one is on its own line.
        }
       return acc
     },[])

   console.log(Summary)
   MailApp.sendEmail
   MailApp.sendEmail(compareAssignee[0],"pending RPP task(s)",Summary[2])
     }
 }

  function scheduleEmails(){
  // Schedules for the first of every month
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmail")
  .timeBased()
  .onMonthDay(28)
  .atHour(1)
  .create();
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `List item Pulling email address from column 1, task name from column 2, status field “assigned`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: I should have been more prescriptive,
The sheet contains the following columns 1) email 3) task name 6) Status ( state of assigned of fixed). The goal is to send a email to emails in column 1 to remind them of pending task on column 3 based on the status being in assigned state on 6. This will need to run 30th of every month.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted and the discussions have already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussions.

Comment: Any help trouble shoot the issue would eve appreciated! I am still stuck with the two spots mentioned below

Comment: @KaviaVenkatesh If you find that the question doesn't include all the required details, like those being required by commenters, please edit the question to add those details, but if you have new questions derived from the answers, please post them as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send an email at the end of every month to users who have tasks that are still in "assigned" status.

The sendEmail script below finds all the tasks for each user and sends an email to them listing each of their tasks that are still "assigned". **EDIT:** You indicated in a comment above that emails are in Col 1, tasks are in Col 3 and status is in Col6. I updated the code to reflect that below.

Check out this [sample email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TZv7.jpg) to see the results.

The second function creates a trigger that runs `sendEmail` every month. You indicated you wanted to send the email on the last day of the month, but it seems Google has a hard time with that. Some other folks came up with workarounds. I like this one: send the reminder on the 1st of the month, but at 1 in the morning! You can see more of their work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015731/what-happens-when-you-set-a-month-timer-trigger-to-fire-on-the-31st-for-a-month/20027679)

```
function sendEmail(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("status").activate();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  //grab all the data in the sheet, and then filter for any row where the status is still "assigned"
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
  var assigned = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    if(curr[5] === "assigned") {
      acc.push(curr)
    }
    return acc
  },[])

  // From all the tasks still in "assigned" status, get a unique list of emails.
  var uniqueEmails = []
  var compareEmails = []
  for (i=0; i<assigned.length; i++){
    compareEmails.push(assigned[i][0])
  }
  uniqueEmails = [...new Set(compareEmails)]

  //loop through the unique emails, grab all the tasks for each of those users, and send a simple email with the tasks listed. 
  for (var i=0; i<uniqueEmails.length; i++){
    var tasksPerUser = assigned.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
      if(curr[0] === uniqueEmails[i]) {
        acc.push(String.fromCharCode(10) + "pending task: " + curr[2]) //this puts a line break before each task, so when the email is sent each one is on its own line.
      }
      return acc
    },[])

  console.log(tasksPerUser)
  MailApp.sendEmail(uniqueEmails[i],"pending tasks",tasksPerUser)
  }
}

function scheduleEmails(){
// Schedules for the first of every month
ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmail")
  .timeBased()
  .onMonthDay(1)
  .atHour(1)
  .create();
}
```

Comment: Thank You, This is pulling an Error (Attempted to execute sendEmail, but could not save)
I am not sure of the Syntax error: Syntax error. line: 20 file: Email

Comment: can you share your file? Here is the [test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zb51wQdlzfila77aHnoa08T-27shMQOzUs2MgBTvtEQ/edit?usp=sharing) I made based on your descriptions.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13X0FYQ7rWOtYZRKBWF9S3A4lcYJefOV-VrgUGETDqV0/edit#gid=0

Comment: you need to open access to the file, please.

Comment: I have shared it with you, appreciate the help

Comment: Looking at your file I see 2 issues: 1) the email column doesn't include emails, and 2) the status column is using "Assigned" not "assigned".  The second issue will prevent any rows from being found since the matching is case sensitive. So, either use "assigned" in the sheet or update the script where it says `if(curr[5] === "assigned") {` so it uses "Assigned" with the initial cap.

Comment: The two spots I am struggling with are, 1)   console.log(tasksPerUser)
  MailApp.sendEmail(Assignee,"pending tasks",tasksPerUser)
  }
} (invalid email) 2)   uniqueEmails = [...new Set(compareEmails)]

Comment: Even with the above changes, I continue to have a problem. Same two issues mentioned in the above comment

Comment: @KaviaVenkatesh The first error seems to be related to an invalid email so please ensure that the script is pointing to the right places in order to grab email addresses - check the assignment of the sheet name and the column indexes.  The other recommendation I would make is to insert several console.log statements so you can validate what is being generated. That will help with debugging. Finally, once doing that if you still have errors please update the question w/screenshots of the error messages and logs so we can help analyze further. I also put more notes in the sheet you shared.